# How to assign 3 values into a single string

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have an issue with assigning values.

```
 string userlanguages = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [s_langName] from [dbo].[tx_UserLanguages] WHERE [s_ID] ='" + Class1.EmployeeId + "'", objcon);
            if (objcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed) objcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(myDS);
            userlanguages = myDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["[s_langName]"].ToString();
        }
        catch (SqlException exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            objcon.Close();
            Class1.langKnwn = userlanguages;
        }
    }
```

Suppose, Here the myDs contains three values. Then how will i assign them to a single string(in this case 'userlanguages'). I am using the  Class1.langKnwn in another page to display the user selected languages(which may be more than 1 language in many cases).

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

How about somethig like

```
List<string> languages = new List<string>();
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < myDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRow++)
    languages.Add(myDS.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["[s_langName]"].ToString());

userlanguages = String.Join(",", languages);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [s_langName] from [dbo].[tx_UserLanguages] WHERE [s_ID] ='" + Class1.EmployeeId + "'", objcon);
        if (objcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed) objcon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(myDS);
        for(int ndx=0;ndx<myDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;ndx+=1)
         {
             if(ndx==0)
               {
                  userlanguages = myDS.Tables[0].Rows[ndx]["[s_langName]"].ToString();
               }
               else
               {
                  userlanguages = userlanguages+","+ myDS.Tables[0].Rows[ndx]["[s_langName]"].ToString();
               }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, using [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) could be better option in your case.

```
using (SqlConnection objcon= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [s_langName] from [dbo].[tx_UserLanguages] WHERE [s_ID] = @id", objcon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Class1.EmployeeId);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd .ExecuteReader();

    string userlanguages = string.Empty;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string str = reader.GetString(0);
        userlanguages = String.Join(",", userlanguages);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use `using System.Text;` namesapce

and then write that code in your block

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < myDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRow++)
        {
            sb.Append(myDS.Tables[0].Rows[iRow]["[s_langName]"].ToString());
            sb.Append(",");
        }
```

// to get the string at the end
            `string myString = sb.ToString();`

`myString=  myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 1);`

Comment: Note that this will end up with an extra `,` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
userlanguages = string.Join(",",  myDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(row => row.Field<string>("[s_langName]"))
                                      .ToArray());
```